# A script in ruby to find all instances of """ and replace with """"

Tags: ruby, regex, string, replace

I have this issue where I need to replace a single double quote around text with two double quotes. Sample line is below.

"1",""Unknown"","""","""",""Unknown"","""",""Unknown"","""","False","1077.36","132","8.1618","97","483","1","51","2010-06-17 20:58:00","2013-12-04 12:05:00","101",""White Oak"","0","0","1","1"

So for example, the before the first comma, I would like what is in the parens. (""1"") The script I am using looks like this.

```
file_names = ['test.csv']

file_names.each do |file_name|

  text = File.read(file_name)

File.write(file_name, text.gsub(/"/, "\"\""))

end
```

If mt regex looks like this /"{1}/ it will pick up every single double quote so that doesn't seem to work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you are not sure if a regex is gonna work you can use this tool: http://rubular.com/ to test it.

Comment: That's how I got as far as I am! Thanks. Unfortunately, I may have to change my tactic with this problem. I don't see of an option that will help me here.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you want any instance of `"..."` be replaced by `""...""`, but only if the `...` was surrounded by a single double quote on either side. Some of your values already have two double quotes on both sides and should be left untouched. For example, `""Unknown""` should remain `""Unknown""` and should not become `""""Unknown""""`.

I assumed your 'sample line' is a single String, i.e., it should be enclosed in quotes to declare it as String which I did in my code -- I enclosed it in single quotes to avoid a lot of escaping of double quotes.

The regular expression I use uses negative lookbehind and lookahead to identify only those double quotes which are not preceded or followed by another double quote and replaces those with two double quotes.

```
line = '"1",""Unknown"","""","""",""Unknown"","""",""Unknown"","""","False","1077.36","132","8.1618","97","483","1","51","2010-06-17 20:58:00","2013-12-04 12:05:00","101",""White Oak"","0","0","1","1"'
line.gsub(/(?<!")"(?!")/, '""')
```

This results in this (without enclosing quotes):

```
""1"",""Unknown"","""","""",""Unknown"","""",""Unknown"","""",""False"",""1077.36"",""132"",""8.1618"",""97"",""483"",""1"",""51"",""2010-06-17 20:58:00"",""2013-12-04 12:05:00"",""101"",""White Oak"",""0"",""0"",""1"",""1""
```

So to apply this to your code, simply replace the `File.write` line with:

```
File.write(file_name, text.gsub(/(?<!")"(?!")/, '""'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to do the replacement in a single regexp gsub, you could first replace two double quotes with something different (e.g. a never occuring utf-8 sign), then replace the one double quote with 2 double quotes and finally replace the special character with the 2 double quotes again.